# pip warn or stop when it cannot install the latest version of a package specified on the commandline?

Tags: python, pip

I just created a new version of one of my Python modules, lets name it `abc.klm`, created its packages and pushed both the package to the caching `devpi` instance I use in my network. Since I have tool to bump the major/minor/micro version of a module, I am often not paying attention to the actual version of a module, especially if no other module is depending on that. *I always just want to use the latest version*.

This latest version of `abc.klm` is dependent on (new) capabilities provided with a specific version of a library package `abc.xyz`. So I have an install requirement `abc.xyz>0.12.1`. In general I am also not so concious of what is the latest version of a library package, in general making sure there is backwards compatibility.

On a new server I wanted to use the commandline utility `klm` provided by `abc.klm`, so I created a new virtualenv. Then I used `pip install abc.klm`, which is set up to use the caching `devpi` , to install `abc.klm`.

But when I tried to use the `klm` utility I noticed after a while, I was working with an old version of `abc.klm`.
This was because I had not noticed that the actual latest version of `abc.klm` available was not used because I had forgotten to upload a version of `abc.xyz` newer than 0.12.1, so pip installed an older version of `abc.klm` for which all dependencies could be matched. (My development and testing machine is set up differently and did not have this problem).

If I had memorised the version number of `abc.klm` that I had just created and wanted to use, and had then checked the screen and a half of output of `pip` that installing the 30 or so dependencies generated, I could have seen that that latest version was silently not installed.

How can I get `pip` to break off an install, or at least clearly complain, when not being able to install the latest version of `abc.klm`, and any other packages direclty specified on the commandline?

I am looking for a config or commandline option, not copying over requirement files or other things. Installing should be simple given the amount of packages and servers I deal with. So if this functionality is missing from `pip`, I'll probably write a wrapper program that handles getting the latest version numbers available for the commandline specified packages and explicitly pass these on to `pip`.